# How to select dates where some dates of range are in given range?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause, date-range

My table `presences` holds time ranges, where an employee is present. The range has a `start` date and `end` date.

I know how to select a date being in a date range, by simply using `BETWEEN` but, what I want to do, is to provide a given date range, e.g. `2022-04-04 to 2022-04-06` and I want to get all rows where an employee as available at at least one day of the given range.

When the `presences` table has a row with start 2022-01-01 and end 2022-12-31, what means, the employee is present **every day**, then the row must be returned, because the provided range is in the presence range.

Another example, an employee is present on 2022-04-05 only, then this row must be returned as well, as the employee is present at least once in the provide range.

Here is a fiddle from what I got so far:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b3506/4

Comment: What does this row: `("2022-04-05 00:00:00", "2022-04-05 00:00:00")` in your sample data mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the date value of `start` to the end date and the date value of `end` to the start date of the queried date range:

```
SELECT *
FROM presences
WHERE DATE(start) <= '2022-04-06' AND DATE(end) >= '2022-04-04';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c0fd4fb15d9eeb6e49508a61f8d76b58).

Comment: Crazy easy, when you see it, but hard to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add `DATE` if the column is date type already, perhaps, if its not date, you need to cast it to date. But this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM presences
WHERE start >= '2022-04-04' AND end <= '2022-04-06';
```

Comment: Check the demo link the OP provided. Both columns are timestamps.

Comment: Yeah, adding ```DATE``` or not would still work.

Comment: No, it would not work if the time in the timestamps is not `00:00:00`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=413d81a47e3f2f0ee0e2e3938f6307b3. I just edited your demo.

Comment: What about this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbaa1a35aa25e00dae69ca23af23c6f5? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Understood, thanks